# IllegalArgumentException - Hibernate Error - org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Clasa is not mapped [SELECT c FROM Clasa c]

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I have the following line of code, in which I'm trying to get all users from a class, by using JPQL syntax:
`

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.util.List;

public class ClasaDao {

    private EntityManager em;

    public ClasaDao(EntityManager em){
        this.em = em;
    }

    public List<Clasa> getClase(){

        String sql = "SELECT c FROM Clasa c";

        TypedQuery<Clasa> query = em.createQuery(sql, Clasa.class);

        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public void stergeClasa(Clasa clasa){

        clasa = em.merge(clasa);
        em.remove(clasa);
    }}`
```

and this is the Entity class:

```
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Clasa")
    public class Clasa implements Serializable {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;
    
        @Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date dataIncepere;
    
        private String nume;
    
        @ManyToOne
        private Curs curs;
    
        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "clasa")
        private List<Student> student;
    
        public List<Student> getStudent() {
            return student;
        }
    
        public void setStudent(List<Student> student) {
            this.student = student;
        }
    
        public Clasa getClasa() {
            return clasa;
        }
    
        public void setClasa(Clasa clasa) {
            this.clasa = clasa;
        }
    
        private Clasa clasa;
    
        public Curs getCurs() {
            return curs;
        }
    
        public void setCurs(Curs curs) {
            this.curs = curs;
        }
    
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public Date getDataIncepere() {
            return dataIncepere;
        }
    
        public void setDataIncepere(Date dataIncepere) {
            this.dataIncepere = dataIncepere;
        }
    
        public String getNume() {
            return nume;
        }
    
        public void setNume(String nume) {
            this.nume = nume;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Clasa{" +
                    "dataIncepere=" + dataIncepere +
                    ", nume='" + nume + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

The lines above yield the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Clasa is not mapped [SELECT c FROM Clasa c]

Any ideas as to what might be causing this error will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it says it's not mapped, then the class is not included in the persistence unit. Check you persistence.xml if you listed the class there or maybe add `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "clasa")
```

should be rather:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "Clasa")
```

This may be causing the IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Thanks! Really pleased! @user12966448 Please could you add a vote to the question.